# python: find out if running in shell or not (e.g. sun grid engine queue)

Tags: python, shell, terminal, stdout

is there a way to find out from within a python program if it was started in a terminal or e.g. in a batch engine like sun grid engine?

the idea is to decide on printing some progress bars and other ascii-interactive stuff, or not.

thanks!

p.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Pavel. If any of the responses below solve your problem, you may wish to officially accept the one that you feel provided the best answer; the answerer gets a few extra points, and it helps future visitors to the identify the best solution.

Comment: by the way, what about running `printenv` in a job and see which environment variables are set by Sun Grid Engine (such as the job number) which are not set during a typical interactive shell ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Checking for interactive shell in a Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108330/checking-for-interactive-shell-in-a-python-script)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The standard way is `isatty()`.

```
import sys
if sys.stdout.isatty():
    print("Interactive")
else:
    print("Non-interactive")
```

Comment: thank you very much, works just as intended! exactly what i looked for.

p.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `os.getppid()` to find out the process id for the parent-process of this one, and then use that process id to determine which program that process is running. More usefully, you could use `sys.stdout.isatty()` -- that doesn't answer your title question but appears to better solve the actual problem you explain (if you're running under a shell but your output is piped to some other process or redirected to a file you probably don't want to emit "interactive stuff" on it either).

Comment: thank you for your explanation, Alex! that helps me a lot!

p.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly shorter:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.isatty()
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found the following to work on both Linux and Windows, in both the normal Python interpreter and IPython (though I can't say about IronPython):

```
isInteractive = hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or hasattr(sys, 'ipcompleter')
```

However, note that when using **ipython**, if the file is specified as a command-line argument it will run before the interpreter becomes interactive. See what I mean below:

```
C:\>cat C:\demo.py
import sys, os

# ps1=python shell; ipcompleter=ipython shell
isInteractive = hasattr(sys, 'ps1') or hasattr(sys, 'ipcompleter')
print isInteractive and "This is interactive" or "Automated"

C:\>python c:\demo.py
Automated

C:\>python
>>> execfile('C:/demo.py')
This is interactive

C:\>ipython C:\demo.py
Automated       # NOTE! Then ipython continues to start up...

IPython 0.9.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object'. ?object also works, ?? prints more.

In [2]: run C:/demo.py
This is interactive    # NOTE!
```

HTH