# How to know if my python is running under an embedded environment?

Tags: python, sys

My script can run under OS shell, or be embedded in another software, which still uses the same interpreter, but not under OS shell.

Is there a way to tell where my script is running in this case?
Will I know with the `sys` module?

Comment: See if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108330/checking-for-interactive-shell-in-a-python-script?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Depends what you mean by 'embedded' and how the software invokes the script. There may be a few ways to differentiate these two cases.